# setting font size and highlighting comments in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

How do I set the font size of comments in emacs. I want the comments to be smaller in size than the rest of the code. I also want it to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run <kbd>M-x customize-face font-lock-comment-face</kbd> and set the `height` attribute, along with `background` and `foreground` to how you want the comments to be highlighted.

To persist this between sessions, choose `Save for future sessions` from the customization screen or add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:background "yellow" :foreground "red" :height 0.5)))))
```

Comment: could you please give the code for it? I want to do it in the .emacs file.

Comment: You can save it to your `.emacs` by saving the customization for future sessions.  Added this code the answer.

Comment: Just beware: you do not want to have more than one call to `custom-set-faces` in your `.emacs`.  I.e. if you want to change several faces, do it within the same `custom-set-faces`.